# Github linking existing code to a repo

Tags: github

I have a repo and it contains some code.

My friend has the code which I sent to him via a USB stick. So his code folder does not link to my repo.

I wonder if there is anyway to link his code base to my repo without doing clone(since it's Giga bytes big)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new remote.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

then verify the remote:

```
git remote -v

# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

check the [github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote) for more info.